# Galois Group of Ordered Field containing Square Roots

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, order-theory, radicals, ordered-fields

Given a ordered field $K$ such that every positive element $0<x$ has a root in $K$ we can show that any endomorphism $f:K\rightarrow K$ preserves the ordering of $K$ and turns out to be $\text{id}_K$. It follows that $\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})=\{\text{id}_K\}$.

So now I want to find some examples of such $K$, we of course have $K=\mathbb{R}$. Another example I have found is $K=\mathbb{A}\cap\mathbb{R}$ where $\mathbb{A}\subset\mathbb{C}$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$. Do you know any other examples (or families of such examples for that matter)?

Regards

Comment: That an endomorphism preserve the order of $K$ does not imply that this endomorphism is the identity. For instance in the field $\mathbb{Q}(X)$ where $\frac{P(X)}{Q(X)}>0$ iff $\lim\limits_{q\to+\infty} \frac{P(q)}{Q(q)} >0$, the endomorphism over $\mathbb{Q}$ sending $X$ on $X^2$ preserves the order.

Comment: I forgot to add that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $K$. Given $k\in K$ we have that $k=\text{inf}\,\mathbb{Q}_{>k}$ and $k=\text{sup} \,\mathbb{Q}_{<k}$, so since $f$ is the identity on $\mathbb{Q}$ and preserves the order we find that $k\le f(k)$ and $f(k) \le k$, so $k=f(k)$ and $f$ is the identity on $K$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A large class of reasonably well-studied examples is given by the [real closed fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field), which can be defined as the ordered fields such that every positive element has a square root and such that every polynomial of odd degree has a root. The Wikipedia article gives [several examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field#Examples_of_real_closed_fields), such as the [nonstandard reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number).

By the way, I would not personally refer to the automorphism group of a non-Galois extension as a Galois group; such extensions e.g. don't have a Galois correspondence. They're just automorphism groups.

Comment: Thanks, very nice :) As I mentioned in my other comment I forgot to add that $\mathbb{Q}$ has to be dense in the field $K$. Does this also hold for real closed fields? If I recall correctly, it isn't dense in the Hyperreals.